# Learning polymorphism and the equals class

Tags: java

I'm currently reading up on polymorphism and am getting kind of confused with the content. The bit on dynamic binding in my book is very confusing to me as well, but I'm not sure what example to give, perhaps somewhat can give an easy example to describe how dynamic binding works ? All I know is that when calling a method(?) on a certain type, it will call the most specific method that the instance is tied to.

Also, when using the equals method, why is it bad practice to override java's equals method with one such as this:

```
public boolean equals(Circle circle){
return this.radius == circle.radius;
}
```

as opposed to

```
 public boolean equals(Object circle){
return this.radius == ((Circle)circle).radius;
}
```

Sorry if this is kind of jumbled, I'm having a hard time understanding these concepts that I feel are crucial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first you aren't override-ing, you are overloading.

Comment: The second  one will throw an exception if you pass it something that isn't a `Circle`.

Comment: Once you start getting the hang of this and writing your own overriding methods, it's good practice to write `@Override` before the method definition.  That way, if it's not really overriding (like your first `equals` example), the compiler will let you know.  `@Override` was added to the language to prevent exactly this kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

The `equals` method on the `Object` class takes an `Object` as a parameter.  So this method

```
public boolean equals(Circle circle){
```

has a different signature and thus *overloads* the `equals` method; it does not override it.  The major point of polymorphism is that you can have an object reference of a superclass (say, `Object`) refer to an actual object of a subclass (here, `Circle`), and you can call a method on the superclass reference, not care what the actual class is, and the method of the class of the actual instance is called.

You can have such an overloaded method, but it won't be called if you have an `Object` reference, even if the parameter being passed in is really a `Circle`.

Comment: so in this case, the equals method would return false if the declared type of the object being passed is not of type Circle?

Comment: It is best practice to return `false` in your `Circle` class's `equals` method if the passed in object is not a `Circle`.  Note in your case, a `ClassCastException` would result if `circle` wasn't really a `Circle`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to answer your question pretty well:

http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice because overloading (compared to overriding) equals might lead to unexpected behaviour. Let's suppose your `Circle` class had this base class:

```
class Shape {
  @Overrides
  public void equals(Object other) {
  }

  public void equals(Shape other) {
  }
}
```

Let's further suppose there is a class `Triangle` which also extends `Shape`. Now what would happen when you call this:

```
circle.equals(triangle);
```

`Shape.equals(Shape)` will be called, not `Circle.equals(Object)`, because it's the closest match for the Triangle type. That's surprising! ;)

I've once written a blog post about polymorphism and `equals()`: [Java polymorphism and equals()](https://ewirch.github.io/2014/01/java-polymorphism-and-equals.html)